# Pass variable from python file to bash script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I am trying to pass variables from python to bash script. I have python file init.py in that file i have to variables that variables i want to call using bash script. but i am unable to call. i tried like
in python file (init.py)

```
server = os.environ('in_server')
database = os.environ('in_database')
tokenstruct=MSI_token()
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';',attrs_before={1256:bytearray(tokenstruct)})
    cursor= cnxn.cursor()
```

in bash file:

```
export in_server=${OUT_SERVER}
export in_database=${OUT_DATABASE}
OUT_SERVER = url
OUT_DATABASE = database name
```

but its not working for me. How can i call python variables in bash script?

[image: error]

Comment: Can you please help me on this issue asap

Comment: how are you calling ur bash script in python ? 
if the vars exist as env variables, you dont need to pass them to ur bash script. You can just access them from ur bash script directly

Comment: So, can't you just set them when you do a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) call from your Python script to run the bash.sh?

Comment: @AFFISHMOHAMMAD : _from python to bash script_ : I don't see any invocation of a bash program in the Python code which you posted.

Comment: The issue description is unclear, but what i'm able to comprehend is that you're trying to export the variables from the bash file into your python script, then maybe you try by removing the spaces around the `=` from your bash file, example: `OUT_SERVER=url`  and  `OUT_DATABASE=database name` ...but this is just a guess from my PoV.Thanks!

Comment: I am doing in init.py file i have server and database names those are change when environment will change. I need to call server and database variables in bash script and i need to run that bash script in azure cicd pipeline. I have given server and database details in devops pipeline environment variables.

Comment: i have given OUT_SERVER=url and OUT_DATABASE=database but its not working.

Comment: variables are inside in python file that variables in need to call from bash script.

Comment: I am not declaring my values in python file. I will declare my values in bash script then how can i do. could you please help me

Comment: I don't want to pass value in python script. I want to pass only variable in python and i will call that variable from python and pass value in bash script

Comment: Like in python script: server = os.environ('in_server') database = os.environ('in_database') In Bash script: export in_server=${OUT_SERVER} export in_database=${OUT_DATABASE} OUT_SERVER = server.com OUT_DATABASE = dbname

Comment: terminal is same but file locations are different

Comment: Can you please any one help me on my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this in your `bash` script

```
echo "var=$var"
```

then from python, you can call

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

env = {'var': 'val'}
subprocess.run(['myscript'], env=env)
```

and you'll receive

```
var=val
```

Comment: Like in python script: server = os.environ('in_server') database = os.environ('in_database') In Bash script: export in_server=${OUT_SERVER} export in_database=${OUT_DATABASE} OUT_SERVER = server.com OUT_DATABASE = dbname

Comment: I don't want to pass value in python script. I want to pass only variable in python and i will call that variable from python and pass value in bash script

Answer (score 0):

in your python script you can set a environment variable,

```
import os

#Set environment variables
os.environ['VARIABLE'] = 'VALUE'
```

in your bash script in the same terminal session, you can call the environment variable.

Comment: I don't want to pass value in python script. I want to pass only variable in python and i will call that value from python and pass value in bash script.

Comment: Like in python script:
server = os.environ('in_server')
database = os.environ('in_database')
In Bash script:
export in_server=${OUT_SERVER}
export in_database=${OUT_DATABASE}
OUT_SERVER = http://server.com
OUT_DATABASE = dbname

Comment: terminal is same but file locations are different